# Django Admin Using both Django Reversion and Django-Import-Export

Tags: python, django, admin, django-reversion

I am trying to enable Django Reversion and Django-Import-Export for the same model... Not sure if my logic is correct or if I should be using multiple admin.py files etc

I have tried the following but this only allows Django Reversion to work, If I switch them around Import Export Works. It would be awesome if I could have both enabled at the same time.

```
class MyModelAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I have had a look at readthedocs for both Projects but am still lost.

http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#admin
https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Cheers
xc0m

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem I fixed it by extending the Django admin change_list template and adding the links through that example below.

```
***change_list.html****    
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% load i18n %} 

{% block object-tools %}
  {% if has_add_permission %}
    <ul class="object-tools ">
      {% block object-tools-items %}
        {% if not is_popup %}
          <li><a href="import/" class="import_link">{% trans "Import" %}</a></li>
          <li><a href="export/{{ cl.get_query_string }}" class="export_link">{% trans "Export" %}</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{recoverlist_url}}" class="recoverlink">{% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|escape as name %}Recover deleted {{name}}{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
       <li><a href="add/{% if is_popup %}?_popup=1{% endif %}" class="addlink">{% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
     {% endblock %}
   </ul>
 {% endif %}
{% endblock %}


***admin.py***
class MyAdmin(ImportExportMixin, MyModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = "change_list.html"
    resource_class = MyResource
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that this method works especially well if using **Django Grappelli**, you can just change the `<ul class="object-tools">` to `<ul class="grp-object-tools">` and it keeps everything pretty! Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: I created a new subclass that adds a similar `change_list_template = "change_list.html"` so this way, I didn't bloat all my models.

Answer (score 4):

**Final result:**

[image: import export recover deleted links]

Inspired from [@Aidan Doherty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27903902/1092815), I created a new class that is a combination of `VersionAdmin`, `ImportMixin`, `ExportMixin` subclasses which extends a custom `change_list_template`.

Here's how it looks:

**`ImportExportVersionModelAdmin.py`:**

```
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin, ExportMixin
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin


class ImportExportVersionModelAdmin(ImportMixin, ExportMixin, VersionAdmin):
    """
    Import, export and Version admin.
    Fixes missing link in change_list admin view :)
    """
    #: template for change_list view
    change_list_template = 'change_list_import_export_version.html'
```

**`templates/change_list_import_export_version.html`:**

```
{% extends "admin/import_export/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <li><a href="import/" class="import_link">{% trans "Import" %}</a></li>
    <li><a href="export/{{ cl.get_query_string }}" class="export_link">{% trans "Export" %}</a></li>
    {% if not is_popup and has_add_permission and has_change_permission %}
        <li><a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'recoverlist' %}" class="recoverlink">{% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|escape as name %}Recover deleted {{name}}{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

This way I can use it like this:

```
class SiteAdmin(ImportExportVersionModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)
```

It's directly inspired from [import_export's admin.py ImportExportMixin](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/admin.py#L404-L409) and [its change_list_import_export.html template](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/templates/admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html), combined with [reversion's template](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/master/reversion/templates/reversion/change_list.html)

Note: You can apply this solution to multiple subclasses :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this with Reversion, but I think you'll want to use the ImportExportMixin:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin

class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportMixin, reversion.VersionAdmin):
    pass
```

That's how I'm using it with another subclass, and it's working great.

Comment: Both `ImportExportMixin` or `ImportExportModelAdmin` are correct. There's only a small problem: Using this way, it fails to generate the urls in the `change_list` view in admin. It will only generate the links from the **first subclass**. (using `ImportExport` first will provide `import` and `export` links, but will hide `Recover deleted 'model'`. Good news is it's only a template problem. Append `/recover` to `change_list` url and you'll get to the right view. Edit model view will display `Show history` link.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is still relevant but here is a quick solution:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {% if not is_popup and has_add_permission and has_change_permission %}
        <li><a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'recoverlist' %}" class="recoverlink">{% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|escape as name %}Recover deleted {{name}}{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

```html
class CampaignAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, VersionAdmin):
  pass
```